# How can I update State properly in switch case in a loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to update state like [1, 2, 3] but what I'm wrong here and how to fix it.

codesanbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-mendeleev-6641iw?file=/src/App.js:0-642

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    run();
  }, []);

  const run = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      let copy = i;
      switch (copy) {
        case 1:
          setValue([...value, copy]);
          break;
        case 2:
          setValue([...value, copy]);
          break;
        case 3:
          setValue([...value, copy]);
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {value.map((item, index) => {
        return <h2>{value[index]}</h2>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: What’re you trying to achieve here? If you want to push all ten numbers into the array, why not do it at once?

Comment: I write this code because I want to test it. The real code I'm doing has same problem with updating state in the switch case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I know how to make state become [1, 2, 3]

just use the previous value in every setState();

```
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      let copy = i;
      switch (copy) {
        case 1:
          setValue((value) => [...value, copy]);
          break;
        case 2:
          setValue((value) => [...value, copy]);
          break;
        case 3:
          setValue((value) => [...value, copy]);
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: Although that will work, there's no reason to make a bunch of stacked state changes. As I said in my answer, just build the new array and set state once. Otherwise you're just making busy-work for React's state change consolidation code. (For the avoidance of doubt: Doing it as above **will not** make the intermediate states render.)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that every time you do `setValue([...value, copy])`, you're overwriting the previous time you did it. `value` is unchanging in that loop.

Instead, build the new array and *then* set it in state. And any time you're building new state based on existing state, it's generally best to use the callback form of the state setter (to ensure that you're not starting with a stale version of `value`).

Example:

```
const run = () => {
    setValue((oldValue) => {
        const newValue = [...oldValue];
        for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            let copy = i; // ** There's no need for this, just use `i`
            switch (copy) {
                case 1:
                    newValue.push(copy); // It's not clear to me why...
                    break;
                case 2:
                    newValue.push(copy); // ...every case does the same..
                    break;
                case 3:
                    newValue.push(copy); // ...thing, but I replicated it
                    break;
            }
        }
        return newValue;
    });
};
```

Old version showing the problem:

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

/*export default*/ function App() {
    const [value, setValue] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        run();
    }, []);

    const run = () => {
        for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            let copy = i;
            switch (copy) {
                case 1:
                    setValue([...value, copy]);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    setValue([...value, copy]);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    setValue([...value, copy]);
            }
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className="App">
            {value.map((item, index) => {
                return <h2>{value[index]}</h2>;
            })}
        </div>
    );
}
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

New version showing the solution:

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

/*export default*/ function App() {
    const [value, setValue] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        run();
    }, []);

    const run = () => {
        setValue((oldValue) => {
            const newValue = [...oldValue];
            for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                let copy = i; // ** There's no need for this, just use `i`
                switch (copy) {
                    case 1:
                        newValue.push(copy); // It's not clear to me why...
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        newValue.push(copy); // ...every case does the same..
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        newValue.push(copy); // ...thing, but I replicated it
                        break;
                }
            }
            return newValue;
        });
    };

    return (
        <div className="App">
            {value.map((item, index) => {
                return <h2>{value[index]}</h2>;
            })}
        </div>
    );
}
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

---

Side note: You need [`key`](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) props on those `h2` elements in the `map` callback.